# Vertically center elements with a responsive way

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, center, vertical-alignment

Learning about Responsive Web Design, I was wondering if there is a standard procedure to center an element(div, image, or whatever) vertically in a responsive way. Not with margin's and padding's pixels, but with a percentage way or something like that in order to have a responsive alingment result. Like horizontal align with bootstrap's center-block or centered rows and cols.

Comment: Is using flex boxes a possibility? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: I Searching in google a posibility?

Comment: Don't use google use bing. Here's a bunch of different techniques on how to center: http://vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/vertical-centering/padding.php this is meant to support ancient browsers too like ie8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS support for display:table](http://caniuse.com/#search=table).

```html
<div style="display:table;background:blue;height:100vh;width:100vw;">
    <div style="display:table-row;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;color:white;font-size:50px;">Blah</div>
    </div>
</div>
```